# Why can't HHVM write to /var/run/hhvm/pid?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, hhvm

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and I installed Apache + MySQL + PHP with the command

`tasksel install lamp-server`

After this, I installed the prebuilt package of HHVM by following the guidelines in HHVM's Wiki

Everything worked great. I didn't touch anything, I just shutdown the computer.

But after I turned the computer back on, it doesn't work anymore. Apache and MySQL start normally and work (well, kind of).

But HHVM doesn't automatically start (I'm assuming, don't know how to check). When I try to run `/etc/init.d/hhvm start`, it says:

`touch: cannot touch '/var/run/hhvm/pid': Permission denied`

I tried with `sudo /etc/init.d...` but didn't work. So then I changed the permissions of all files and folders within `/var` to the currently logged in user (this was a little stupid from what I hear). It also didn't work.

What is going on ? Why doesn't HHVM work, considering that I initially changed absolutely no file permissions or configuration or... anything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the default init script for HHVM is not intelligent enough to create the directory `/var/run/hhvm` before it tries to create a file there? Or doesn't set the permissions correctly? Or it runs before `/var/run` is mounted? And, yes, blindly mass-changing permissions or ownership of files as a Hail Mary method of attempting to solve a problem you haven't gained an understanding of is at the very least rather unwise...

Comment: You should have run tasksel under sudo as in xxx$ sudo tasksel. Post the output of ls -ltr on /var/run/hhvm/

Comment: Can you `touch /var/run/hhvm/pid` yourself?

Comment: @Sina No I cannot do `touch /var/run/hhvm/pid`, which is weird because I'm the owner of that directory.

Comment: @apesa I don't think I'll be able to do it. My Ubuntu installation just blew up for no reason (can't log in anymore), I have to reinstall it... If I find a solution to this, I will post it here :)